# Cant get program to display properly in java

Tags: java, printwriter

So im trying to invoke my toString method in my AccountWithException class to print the user input contained in the file as well, but for some reason i cant crack as to why it wont print. I tried to do System.out.println(pw.toString())..only to get the memory location constantly being printed to me. Initially i was just reading the file back in however my instructor specified this: "Use the overloaded toString method to output to the console and file (via PrintWriter)" I used the overloaded toString for my object but cant figure it out for my file. Is there something ive overlooked in my code or is this a simple Sysout.println() statement? Requirements have been added.

1.) Prompt user for an output filename. Create a file for text output.

2.) If file exists prompt user for a new filename. Do not continue until a valid, non existing filename is entered and file is opened for output.

3.) Prompt user for first name, last name, balance, (account id and annual interest rate can be constants)

4.) Create AccountWithExceptionObject that includes the user specified data.

5.) If valid data in the object exists: output the object information to the display AS WELL AS the opened output file. USE the overloaded toString() method when outputting the data. If invalid data exists (< 0) then throw your custom InvalidBalanceException.

6.) Use finally block to ensure output file has been properly closes.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.File;
//import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
//import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
//import java.io.FileReader;
//import java.io.BufferedReader;

public class TestAccountWithException {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InvalidBalanceException, FileNotFoundException, IOException {
        // variable declaration
        String fileName;
        String firstName;
        String lastName;
        double balance;
        int id = 1122;
        final double RATE = 4.50;

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("Please enter a file name: ");
        fileName = input.next();
        File fw = new File(fileName + ".txt");

        // while loop to check if file already exists

        while (fw.exists()) {
            System.out.print("File already exists, enter valid file name: ");
            fileName = input.next();
            fw = new File(fileName + ".txt");
        }

        System.out.print("Enter your first name: ");
        firstName = input.next();

        System.out.print("Enter your last name: ");
        lastName = input.next();

        // concatanate full/last name
        String fullName = firstName.concat(" " + lastName);

        System.out.print("Input beginnning balance: ");
        balance = input.nextDouble();

        PrintWriter pw = null;
        // pass object to printwriter and pw to write to the file
        pw = new PrintWriter(fw);
        // print to created file
        pw.println(firstName);
        pw.println(lastName);
        pw.println(balance);
        pw.println(id);
        pw.println(RATE);


        String line = null;


        try {

            // pass user input to object
            AccountWithException acctException = new AccountWithException(fullName, balance, id, RATE);

            System.out.println(acctException.toString());


            // create the object
            //FileReader fr = new FileReader(fileName + ".txt");
            // pass to buffered reader and use its preset commands for alteration to file
            //BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);
            //System.out.println("Text file opened and reading...");

            // read in lines from file
        //  while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                //System.out.println(line);
            //}
            // close buffered reader
            //br.close();

            // custom exception if balance < 0
        } catch (InvalidBalanceException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        //} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            //System.out.println("File not found" + fileName);
        //} catch (IOException e) {
            //System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        } finally {
            System.out.println("Text file closing...");
            pw.close();

        }

    } // end main
} // end class


public class AccountWithException {
  private int id;
  private double balance;
  private static double annualInterestRate;
  private java.util.Date dateCreated;
  // CRE additions for lab assignment
  private String name;

  // no-arg constructor to create default account
  public AccountWithException() {
    this.dateCreated = new java.util.Date();
  }


  //constructor for test account with exception that takes in arguments
  public AccountWithException(String newName, double newBalance, int newId, double newRate) throws InvalidBalanceException {
       setName(newName);
       setBalance(newBalance);
       setId(newId);
       setAnnualInterestRate(newRate);
       this.dateCreated = new java.util.Date();
  }

  /* // constructor for test account with exception that takes in arguments
  public AccountWithException(String newName, double newBalance, int newId, double newRate) {
      this.name = newName;
      this.balance = newBalance;
      this.id = newId; 
      AccountWithException.annualInterestRate = newRate;
      this.dateCreated = new java.util.Date();
  }    */


  // accessor methods
  public int getId() {
    return this.id;
  }

  public double getBalance() {
    return this.balance;
  }

  public static double getAnnualInterestRate() {
    return annualInterestRate;
  }

  public double getMonthlyInterest() {
    return this.balance * (this.annualInterestRate / 1200);
  }

  public java.util.Date getDateCreated() {
    return this.dateCreated;
  }

  public String getName() {
    return this.name;
  }

  // mutator methods
  public void setId(int newId) {
    this.id = newId;
  }

  public void setBalance(double newBalance) throws InvalidBalanceException {

      if(newBalance >= 0) {
        this.balance = newBalance;
      }
      else {
        throw new InvalidBalanceException(newBalance);
      }
  }   

  public static void setAnnualInterestRate(double newAnnualInterestRate) {
    annualInterestRate = newAnnualInterestRate;
  }

  public void setName(String newName) {
    this.name = newName;
  }

  // balance modification methods
  public void withdraw(double amount) {
    this.balance -= amount;
  }

  public void deposit(double amount) {
    this.balance += amount;
  }

  // override of Object method
  public String toString() {
    // return string with formatted data 
    // left-align 20 character column and right-align 15 character column
    return String.format("%-20s%15d\n%-20s%15tD\n%-20s%15s\n%-20s%15.2f%%\n%-20s%,15.2f\n",
      "ID:", this.id,
      "Created:", this.dateCreated,
      "Owner:", this.name,
      "Annual Rate:", this.annualInterestRate,
      "Balance:", this.balance);
  }
}

public class InvalidBalanceException extends Exception {

    private double balance;

    public InvalidBalanceException(double balance) {
        // exceptions constructor can take a string as a message
        super("Invalid Balance " + balance);
        this.balance = balance;
    }

    public double getBalance() {
        return balance;
    }



}
```

Comment: Just as a general tip: just because one of the methods in your class throws an exception does not mean you have to name the class `__WithException`. The `throws` clause always appears to clients if you write your javadocs properly.

Comment: Thanks! Instructor just wants us to name the class that way since its an intro level course..

Answer (score 0):

Try to slap an @Override on your tostring method.

```
  // override of Object method
  @Override
  public String toString() {
    // return string with formatted data 
    // left-align 20 character column and right-align 15 character column
    return String.format("%-20s%15d\n%-20s%15tD\n%-20s%15s\n%-20s%15.2f%%\n%-20s%,15.2f\n",
      "ID:", this.id,
      "Created:", this.dateCreated,
      "Owner:", this.name,
      "Annual Rate:", this.annualInterestRate,
      "Balance:", this.balance);
  }
}
```

Also, when naming your classes, you shouldn't put "WithException" on them if they throw an exception. This class should simply be "Account".

Comment: in which class r u referring to?

Comment: AccountWithException, which is the one you're trying to print, right?

Comment: No thats printed in the first try-catch line: System.out.println(acctException.toString())

Comment: Im trying to print all the info in the toString method directly only in the console not anywhere else. But we're supposed to only use printwriter to accomplish this according to what instructor specifed: "Use the overloaded toString method to output to the console and file (via PrintWriter).  There is no need to read from file."

Comment: System.out.println() will print to the console. To print to your file, you'll use your PrintWriter.

Comment: You said you're getting the object reference when you try to print it. that's a tell-tale sign that you need to put an override annotation on your toString. Just try it and see if it fixes it.

Comment: Sorry i wasnt clear just re read that. I got the object to print fine. I used the overloaded toString for my object but cant figure it out for my file. I read the file in and just outputted line by line but thats not whats required. Apparently im supposed to use the toString method again but do it via printwriter. I dont understand how thats possible?

Comment: Could you please post what the requirements are for the assignment?

Comment: -1 because adding `@Override` does has no effect (in this case) and therefore does not help.

Comment: Thanks Bohemian, real helpful.